# How to Use one function for input classes with diffrent id's

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on a new project and i have created a search  where users can search the app for other users.

So basically i have a price input box  and a counter beside  for every user.
The problem is It only changes the value of the price for the first user that was queried from the SQL database.

I know its because i put an id on the price form field.

I just don't know to how to to get values for  other users after the first one
and I don't know how to write a code without using 'get element by id' .

I am new to javascript any help would be appreciated please.

Thanks.

Here's the php and mysql code:

```
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testing");
        $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){

            if($row['image'] == ""){
                echo "<span class = 'userpic'><img width='100' height='100' src='images/verify.jpg' alt='Default Profile Pic'> </span>";
            } else {
                echo "<span class = 'userpic'><img width='100' height='100' src='images/".$row['image']."' alt='Profile Pic'</span>";
            }


            echo "
                  <span class = 'username'>".$row['username']."</span>
                  <form name = 'matchcreator' class = 'amount' action='arena.php' method ='post'>
                  <input class='price' textarea class='price-box' type='text' id='price1' name='price' size='1' maxlength = '15' value='0'/>
                  <button class='up' type ='button' onclick='incrementValue();'><img src='images/up.png'  width='10px' height='10px' href='#'> </button>
                  <button class='down' type ='button' onclick='decreaseValue();' ><img src='images/down.png' width='10px' height='10px' href='#'></button>
                  <div class = 'light'>
                  </div>
                  <div class = 'light2'>
                  </div>
                  <div class = 'light3'>
                  </div>
                  <div class = 'light4'>
                  </div>
                  <div class = 'light5'>
                  </div>
                  <button class='send' type = 'submit' onclicl=onclick='return confirm('Are you sure?')'>Send Challenge</button>
                  </form>
                   ";               
            echo "<br>";
        }
            ?>
```

Here's the javascript :

```
         function  incrementValue()
          {
      var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('price1').value, 0);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value++;
      document.getElementById('price1').value = value;
      }
      function decreaseValue()
      {
      var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('price1').value, 0);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value--;
      document.getElementById('price1').value = value;
      }
```

Please kindly  help me out

Comment: You got multiple errors in your HTML-markup. `<input class='price' textarea class='price-box' type='text'...`, What is "textarea" in this context? `onclicl=onclick='return confirm('Are you sure?')'`..  and there's more. Start by making sure the HTML is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) if you're not really experienced with Java Script.

With jQuery this is very easily accomplished by doing:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input class='price' textarea class='price-box' type='text' id='price1' name='price' size='1' maxlength = '15' value='0'/>
  <button class='up' type ='button' onclick='change();'>
  <button class='down' type ='button' onclick='change();'>
  <script>
    function change(){
      var text = $(".price").text();
      alert(text + " " + $.isNumeric(text));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title and question do not seem to mirror each other. The question:

"How to Use one function for input classes with diffrent id's"

Use jQuery.
To use one function with onclick by id, class, element

ELEMENT:

```
$('element').on('click',function(){
//do something.......
});
```

ID:

```
$('#id').on('click',function(){
//do something.......
});
```

CLASS:

```
$('.class').on('click',function(){
//do something.......
});
```

MULTIPLE ID's

```
$('#id1').add('#id2').on('click',function(){
//do something.......
});
```

Or just fire the onclick attribute.
Your HTML

```
<button name="x" id="x" onclick="doSomething();">
```

The Function

```
function doSomething(){
//do something.......
}
```

Instead of using "on.('click',function) you could also use:

```
$('.class1').add('.class2').add('.class3').click(function(){
//do something.........
});
```

You can also mix it up and add IDs, Classes, and elements but it makes managing the firing of all of these clicks a pain.

Be sure to put your javascript and or jquery between `<script></script>` tags if you have them in your HTML markup. Only mentioning this since you say you are not very familiar with Javascript.

You could also set the jQuery click methods when the document loads like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//put any one of the above methods here.

});
```

Comment: Or just `$('.class1 .class2 .class3').click(function(){`